# Text snippets shared across posts

Tags: admin, database, sidebar

I'd like to add a "fast facts" section to a wordpress site - an area in the sidebar where snippets of text are rotated.

Where is the best place to store things like this?  Widgets don't really allow repeated items grouped in a good way & i don't want to add a post type as that would be available as a page with a URL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you *do* want a custom post type, you just want to set the `public` argument to `false`. The [`register_post_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) has lots of arguments that will let you do everything you probably want. Along with `public`, you'll probably set `has_archive` to `false`. Setting `show_ui` to `true` will allow you to manage the posts in the backend.

If you want to group the "fast facts" in any way, register a taxonomy to go along with your post type.

Obviously, you'll still have to fill in some blanks and write a widget to put into the sidebar, but I think this answers your main question.

Comment: Yeah cool ok, sounds good.  I like that the data type will be extendable like that.  Good one.