# Is there a WordPress equivalent to MediaWiki templates

Tags: posts, pages, visual-editor

I'm new to WordPress and already in dire need of a way to reuse common page content.  For example we have 10+ product pages and in different areas of each product's page I want to include a textual statement.  In MediaWIKI they have a system of [Templates](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Templates) which area awesome!  You define a template with the content you want included and then include the template in pages.  It's like a pre-processor merge system and will dump the contents of the template into the page where it's called for.

The following topics seem to be close to what I want but not exactly

- [Text snippets shared across posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/81748/text-snippets-shared-across-posts)
- [Turn a snippet of HTML and PHP into a shortcode](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103984/turn-a-snippet-of-html-and-php-into-a-shortcode)

I found the [Post Snippets](http://wordpress.org/plugins/post-snippets/) plugin and it sounds like it could be a good fit but I wanted to ask here if anyone familiar with MediaWIKI knew of a more appropriate option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have tried the [Post Snippets](http://wordpress.org/plugins/post-snippets/) plugin before asking this question - it's fantastic on does just what I needed it to.  I ran into one slight issue (for me) where simply extracting Page content to a Snippet did not result in the exact same rendered output.  I [posted a question on the support forum](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/snippet-not-wrapped-in-tags?replies=1#post-4706672) and you can check that for a solution maybe.

Comment: I had a brief look on Post Snippets. I don't think the "template" this plugin provides can have logical expression like `{{#if:...}}`.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are two *easy* answers to this , one being an actual template and the other being more of a snippet.

You can use `get_template_part` to call an actual PHP template file, for instance if you have a file called `my-text.php` you could use:

```
get_template_part( 'my-text' );
```

Or if you just want to go the shortcode route and call a snippet in your editor you can do something like:

```
function footag_func() {
     $foo = 'Brown Cow'
     return $foo;
}
add_shortcode('footag', 'footag_func');
// then just use [footag]
```

Comment: Thanks for showing how to do this with PHP.  I should have clarified that I wanted an "editor only" solution.

Comment: Plugin recommendations are off-topic on this site, the shortcode is how you would do it via the editor.